# Emails forwarded from Salesforce case feed to other email addresses with Email-to-Case set up are not generating new cases

Tags: email, email2case, servicecloud, casefeed

I'm wondering if anyone else has ever had this problem and how you solved it.

In our org, we have users who sometimes forward emails from the Case Feed to email addresses for other teams that also have email-to-case set up in Salesforce. Usually these are situations where the user doing the forwarding doesn't realize the team they're emailing is already using Salesforce. The trouble is, while the forwarded email does reach that team's email address, the receiving team expects the email to trigger a new case. But because there's threading in the forward from another case, it never generates a new case for the receiving team--it just ties the email back to the original case.

A group of my end users would really like to be able to have emails forwarded to their teams in this way to actually generate new cases in Salesforce. Has anyone ever dealt with a request like this, and if so, how did you address it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: One possibility involves getting your company's mail server team involved to strip the threading info - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7vJXSAZ